# How do I specify MongoDB API version when Creating Cosmos DB account running the az cosmosdb create command?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cli, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

Currently I have a shell script that has to Create a Cosmos DB account for MongoDB API in an existing resource group in an Azure project.

Bellow is the code snippet that does precisely that

```
az cosmosdb create \
    -n $accountName \
    -g $resourceGroupName \
    --kind MongoDB \
    --default-consistency-level Eventual \
    --locations regionName='West Europe' failoverPriority=0 isZoneRedundant=False \
    --locations regionName='East US' failoverPriority=1 isZoneRedundant=False
```

However this generates a Server Version 3.2 by default.

[image: generates a Server Version 3.2 by default]

My goal is to replicate in an "az" command the following behavior from the UI [where I manually generate a Version 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnFQC.png), resulting in successful [reading of version 3.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJq0G.png)

Do you know what I should change within that code snippet to have it creating directly a [wire protocol 3.6 CosmosDB account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb-feature-support-36)?

Thanks!
Mihai

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `--capabilities EnableMongo` and it will create an account targeting MongoDB version 3.6.

So your command would be:

```
az cosmosdb create \
    -n $accountName \
    -g $resourceGroupName \
    --kind MongoDB \
    --default-consistency-level Eventual \
    --locations regionName='West Europe' failoverPriority=0 isZoneRedundant=False \
    --locations regionName='East US' failoverPriority=1 isZoneRedundant=False \
    --capabilities name=EnableMongo
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this worked for me in the ```--capabilities EnableMongo``` format. Thank you so much!